# Error passing by value in operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to understand why passing by reference works and passing by value does not in a simple class definition

```
#include <iostream>

class Rettangolo {
  int a, b;
  public:
    Rettangolo (Rettangolo& r) {
      a = r.a;
    }
    Rettangolo (int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {};
    Rettangolo operator+= (Rettangolo r1);
    void print() {
      std::cout << a << ", " << b;
    }
};

Rettangolo Rettangolo::operator+= (Rettangolo r1) {
  a += r1.a;
  b += r1.b;
  return *this;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  Rettangolo recta (1, 2);
  Rettangolo rectb (5, 6);
  recta += rectb;
  recta.print ();
}
```

If I use (Rettangolo r1) in the parameter of operator+= as in the example above, the output is "6,2".
But if I use (Rettangolo& r1) in the parameter the output is "6, 8" as I would expect

Comment: Fyi, `operator +=` should return a reference; not a value copy as yours does. Just saying.

Comment: This code contains multiple issues. You should read on copy constructors and operator overloading.

Comment: Your copy constructor should take a const reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your copy constructor is not fully functional. It only copies `a`, and not `b`. Therefore when `rectb` is copied when you call `operator+=`, passing `rectb` by value, the `a` is copied and added to `recta` but the `b` is not copied and therefore not added to `recta`. To fix this, add the `b` copying in the copy constructor, or just delete it, and the compiler will generate a default copy constructor for you that copies both `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code.

The most important issue is that your copy constructor is not copying `b` at all.  When you pass a `Rettangolo` *by value* to `operator+=`, the compiler has to make a copy of it, so inside of your `operator+=` the copied `r1.b` value has an *indeterminate* value, which in your case just happens to be 0, but that is not guaranteed.  Passing `r1` *by reference* instead skips your broken copy constructor.

Also, the copy constructor and `operator+=` need to take a `Rettangolo` by const reference.

Also, your `operator+=` is not returning `*this` by reference, so it is returning another copy (which you are ignoring).

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Rettangolo {
  int a, b;
  public:
    Rettangolo (int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}

    Rettangolo (const Rettangolo& r) : a(r.a), b(r.b) {}
    // or: Rettangolo (const Rettangolo &r) = default;
    // or: simply omit this constructor and let the compiler generate it for you!

    Rettangolo& operator+= (const Rettangolo &r1);

    void print() const {
      std::cout << a << ", " << b;
    }
};

Rettangolo& Rettangolo::operator+= (const Rettangolo &r1) {
  a += r1.a;
  b += r1.b;
  return *this;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  Rettangolo recta (1, 2);
  Rettangolo rectb (5, 6);
  recta += rectb;
  recta.print ();
}
```